# How to slide down a li then .fadeIn() prepend li?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to prepend li with fadein randomly at the same time want to slidedown existing li's.

I have tried follow this but i can't get effect exactly what i want.

```
$("ul#listticker li:first").slideDown(100, function(){
        $('ul#listticker').prepend($('<li>.....</li>').fadeIn(2000));
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the element to slide down, you'll want to use padding instead, as this will force the elements below to move down as well. When inserting the new element, just reset the padding.

```
$("ul#listticker li:first").animate({
    'padding-top': '20px'
}, function(){
    $(this).css('padding-top', '0px');
    $(this).parent().prepend($('<li>.....</li>').fadeIn(1000));
});
```

I'm not sure why the prepended li actually fades in, as it's visible to begin with... nevertheless, it works in this example. If you do experience the li not fading properly, make sure to hide the li first.

**edit:**

I've updated my example to adjust for the height of the inserted li, and use margin instead of padding in case the li has a background of some kind.

http://jsfiddle.net/xixionia/5XhRr/

```
var $li = $('<li style="height:40px;background:lightblue;">New Item</li>').prependTo('ul#listticker').hide();

$li.next().animate({
    'margin-top': $li.height()
}, function() {
    $(this).css('margin-top', '0px');
    $li.fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("ul#listticker li:first").slideDown(100, function(){
    $("<li></li>", { style: "display: none;" }).prependTo("ul#listticker").fadeIn(2000);
});
```